# integer programming problem using dynamic programming approach

Tags: proof-verification, linear-programming, integer-programming, dynamic-programming

Maximise $22x_1 + 33x_2 +22x_3$
Subject to $x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 \leq 4$
where $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$ and are integers

I used the dynamic programming approach to solve this IP problem, i found that there exists no unique solution to this problem and 1 of the solutions to this problem is $(0,0,4)$ would it be possible for someone to verify this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for dynamic programming.

I would solve it this way . . .

Firstly, since each coefficient of the objective function is a multiple of $11$, the triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which maximize
$$f = 22x_1 + 33x_2 +22x_3$$
are the same as the triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which maximize
$$g = 2x_1 + 3x_2 +2x_3$$

Also, since all coefficients of $g$ are positive, there's no need to consider triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ for which $x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 < 4$, since for any such triple, if we increase $x_1$ by $1$, the constraint $x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 \le 4$ would still be satisfied, and the value of $g$ would increase.

Thus, we can assume $x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 = 4$.

But then 
\begin{align*}
g &=  2x_1 + 3x_2 +2x_3\\[4pt]
&= (x_1+2x_2+x_3) + (x_1+x_2+x_3)\\[4pt]
&= 4 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, the triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which maximize $g$ subject to the constraints 
$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0$, and $x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 = 4$, are the same as the triples the triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which maximize $x_1+x_2+x_3$, subject to the same constraints.

The objective function and the constraints are symmetric with respect to the variables $x_1,x_3$, hence we can assume $x_1 \le x_3$, and then at the end, if any solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ has $x_1 < x_3$, we can include the solution $(x_3,x_2,x_1)$ as well.

But there are only $5$ nonnegative integer triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with $x_1 \le x_3$ such that $x_1 +2x_2 +x_3 = 4$, namely
$$(0,0,4),\;\;(0,1,2),\;\;(0,2,0),\;\;(1,0,3),\;\;(1,1,1)$$
and of those, $x_1+x_2+x_3$ is maximized for the triples $(0,0,4)$ and $(1,0,3)$.

Adjusting for the symmetry of $x_1,x_3$, we have the $4$ solutions triples $$(0,0,4),\;(4,0,0),\;(1,0,3),\;(3,0,1)$$
each yielding the same maximum value, $88$, for the original objective function.

Comment: what about (4,0,0) and (3,0,1)?

Comment: Right. Now fixed. Thanks.